# What does it mean to overwrite a file but keep it?

Tags: deleted-files, delete, shred

The `wipe` tool has the option `-k Keep files, i.e. do not remove() them after overwriting`.

What does that mean not to remove a file that was ... well... wiped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manpage](https://github.com/berke/wipe/blob/master/wipe.1) describes `-k` thus:

> Keep  files:  do  not  unlink the files after they have been overwritten. Useful if you want to wipe a device,
>               while keeping the device special file. This implies `-F`.

The main use-case for `-k` is

```
wipe -k /dev/sda
```

which will overwrite all the contents of the drive, without removing the device node.

If you use it on a “standard” file, it will wipe the contents of the file, but leave the file itself (its name, and its presence in the parent directory) alone.

Comment: `on a “standard” file, it will wipe the contents of the file, but leave the file itself (its name, and its presence in the parent directory) alone` - in which case what's left is a zero bit file that is nothing but name and record at a path and cannot be accessed in any way as there is nothing to access (except path/name)

Comment: @cipricus what do you mean by “cannot be accessed in any way”? `echo Hello > test; wipe -k test` leaves behind a file which can be accessed, it no longer contains any useful data but it’s still a valid file. (And the length of the wiped file varies, but isn’t 0.)

Comment: Sorry, just meant "no content can be accessed anymore".

Answer (score 1):

Programs like [`wipe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe) and [`shred`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shred.1.html) that are meant to overwrite file data work using the same interfaces as any other programs. They use the usual OS functions to write e.g. zeroes to the file and hope that the filesystem stores the new data on the same disk blocks as the old data, hence overwriting the old data. They don't have any special method for destroying the data or making the file inaccessible, other than removing them via `unlink()`.

Hence, keeping a file after it's overwritten is just that, the file remains, and is not removed. Only the contents have changed.

An example with `shred`, which doesn't unlink the file by default:

```
$ cat somefile 
some secret data
$ shred somefile 
$ ls -l somefile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 4096 Jun 27 19:28 somefile
$ od -tx1 somefile |head -2
0000000 2b d7 fe 76 a0 4c 79 4e b6 bc 26 7d 6c b0 4e ed
0000020 81 a2 bf 3f ce af ce f0 07 2b fe 80 50 39 e3 c9
```

After the `shred`, the file remains, full of random bytes. The file is not truncated or removed. Its size has actually increased, since `shred` rounds the file size up when overwriting (to overwrite the last data block in full).

Of course we can remove the file with `rm somefile`.

Note that the assumptions the overwriting depends on may not even hold for all filesystems. At least journaling of file data (possible on ext4) and copy-on-write filesystems (btrfs) will make overwriting ineffective by essentially storing multiple copies of the data.